# Do something after activity's layout has been measured but not drawn on screen

Tags: android

Is there a way to do something after the activity's layout has been measured but before it has been drawn on screen?

I need to find out the width of some `ViewGroup` and then add a `View` to it. Right now, I'm doing that in `onWindowFocusChanged()`. But that method is called couple of milliseconds after the layout has been drawn. So the user sees the empty `ViewGroup` for a brief moment, which is quite unpleasant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `View.getViewTreeObserver()` for that purpose. It lets you be notified when a layout has just happened or when a draw is about to occur.

Comment: Thanks, `viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)` worked great.